# Does StringFormat work with this.DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I am binding a TextBlock with a collection in code-behind via this.DataContext = SellerList;
The output is correct but when i apply StringFormat, i see no result. Following is the code for TextBlock on xaml page

```
<TextBlock Name="dateDTKey" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
      Text="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}}" 
      Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBlock}"/>
```

Comment: **Extreme Extreme Apologies** I am really sorry to bother you guys because of my stupidity. 

*Actually i was reading the values of date type into string property rather than DateTime. Because of this Formatting was not being applied.* 

Moderator can feel free to delete this question and i again apologize for the stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for the Binding is a string, if `detailsSellerListingTemplate` is a resource you should use `{StaticResource detailsSellerListingTemplate}`. Also, the TextBlock doesn't need a DataContext for this Binding to work since it's using Source.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DetailsSeller x:Key="detailsSellerListingTemplate"/>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBlock Name="dateDTKey"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource detailsSellerListingTemplate},
                          Path=Date,
                          StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}}"/>
```

This will work if `DetailsSeller` looks similar to this

```
public class DetailsSeller
{
    public DetailsSeller()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You talked about a collection but I can't see how that fits with the binding, so maybe I missunderstood something in the question

Comment: extremely sorry......i miscoded in the question....have updated it.....I am binding this.DataContext = SellerList.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking its because you have way to many braces in your string format.  try this:

```
StringFormat={0:dd-MM-yyyy}
```

Comment: It's not because of this.... because the same code is working for GridViewColumns of listview whose Listview.DataContext is binded to a collection rather than this.Datacontext

Comment: I tried doing this `dateDTKey.DataContext = SellerList` . May be the problem is something else

Comment: well, normally a TextBlock is bound to a single item instead of a collection, that COULD be causing issues.

Comment: No, you can bind the textblock to datacontext. If it hadn't worked, i would have been able to see any result. It's just that formatting isn't applying